# Modis Reprojection Tool mirror or download alternative?

Tags: modis

I need to convert and reproject a complete archive of MODIS *.hdf data.

NASA's Modis Reprojection Tool is literally designed for this, and I even have an old script from the last time I performed this task on this very archive.  However, I can't download the MRT right now because the US Government Shutdown has shut down the download site:

> https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/tools/modis_reprojection_tool
>
> The requested service is temporarily unavailable. It is either overloaded or under maintenance. Please try later.

Does anyone know an alternate repository where I can download the Linux64 (or 32..) source files or .deb for the MRT?

Comment: I guess I can modify my script to use gdalwarp, then check the output against MRT after the US regathers their marbles.

Comment: For the record: the site is back online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for my specific application, subsetting one band of the modis data to a specific region specified in -te,  this seems to work:

> gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:32633 -te xmin ymin xmax ymax -tr xPixelres -yPixelres -srcnodata "32767" -r bilinear input_hdf-eos output.tif

hdf_eos should be in the form:

> HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:/dir/to/MODIS.hdf:MOD_Grid_BRDF:Albedo_BSA_vis

for example, projecting the subdata set describing visible spectrum of Black Sky Albedo